# Infinite recursion with JPA relationship (OneToMany and ManyToOne)

Tags: json, jpa, jackson, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have two JPA entities, Message and File, with the following relationship between it:

```
public class Message implements Serializable {
   ...
   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "message")
   @JsonManagedReference
   private List<File> files;
   ...
}

public class Anexo implements Serializable {
   ...
   @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name = "id_mensagem")
   @JsonBackReference
   private Message message;
   ...
}
```

When I try to query, insert or update using EntityManager, everything wents ok... when I try to delete, i get the following error:

```
Ago 15, 2014 1:21:43 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
Grave: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

I could debug and see that the Message objects has each one a collection of Files and each File has a Message which has a collection of Files, each one with a Message and so...

Why in insert, update and query this isn't an issue but it is when deleting?

Comment: Im also having the exact same problem. If you found a solution, please update your post.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you use some unsafe methods in class **Anexo**, or create a new reference of Message for each Anexo.

NOTE: I suppose you meant `private List<Anexo> files;` in class Message.

You can try a *setMessage* method like this:

```
public void setMessage(Message message) {
    // this is a loop-preventing part
    if (sameAsFormer(message)) {
        return;
    }

    Message formerMessage  = this.message;
    this.message = message;

    if (formerMessage  != null) {
        // this is important, but easy to forget
        formerMessage.removeAnexo(this);
    }

    if (message!= null) {
        message.addAnexo(this);
    }
}
```

where the method *sameAsFormer* is something like:

```
private boolean sameAsFormer(Message message) {
    return this.message==null ? message==null : this.message.equals(message);
}
```

And *removeAnexo* and *addAnexo* methods in class **Message** are something like:

```
public void addAnexo(Anexo anexo) {
    if(getFiles().contains(anexo)) {
        getFiles().set(getFiles().indexOf(anexo), anexo);
    } else {
        getFiles().add(anexo);
    }
    anexo.setMessage(this);
}

public void removeAnexo(Anexo anexo) {
    getFiles().remove(anexo);
    anexo.setMessage(null);
}
```

Please give a look at [this link](http://meri-stuff.blogspot.com/2012/03/jpa-tutorial.html#RelationshipsBidirectionalOneToManyManyToOneConsistency) and [this link](http://notesonjava.wordpress.com/2008/11/03/managing-the-bidirectional-relationship/).

Hope it helps.